# How to know changed function in a new version of js file?

Tags: javascript

In my project I am using ChartJS for generating different types of chart eg, line chart, pie chart, Doughnut chart etc, previously I was using `1.0.2` version of js file and it was working fine but now I changed it to `2.3.0`. After changed I am getting `Error while evaluating javascript input: TypeError: (intermediate value).Line is not a function`.

How to resolve this?

**in 1.0.2 mo code is**

```
var lineChartData = {   
labels: ["Data 1", "Data 2", "Data 3", "Data 4", "Data 5", "Data 6", "Data 7"],
datasets: [{
    fillColor: "rgba(220,220,220,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(220,180,0,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(220,180,0,1)",
    data: [20, 30, 80, 20, 40, 10, 60]
}, {
    fillColor: "rgba(151,187,205,0)",
    strokeColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    pointColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
    data: [60, 10, 40, 30, 80, 30, 20]
}]

}

Chart.defaults.global.animationSteps = 50;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipYPadding = 16;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipCornerRadius = 0;
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipTitleFontStyle = "normal";
Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFillColor = "rgba(0,160,0,0.8)";
Chart.defaults.global.animationEasing = "easeOutBounce";
Chart.defaults.global.responsive = true;
Chart.defaults.global.scaleLineColor = "black";
Chart.defaults.global.scaleFontSize = 16;

var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
var LineChartDemo = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
  pointDotRadius: 10,
  bezierCurve: false,
  scaleShowVerticalLines: false,
  scaleGridLineColor: "black"
});
```

Comment: Read about [releases](https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/releases). There were enough breaking changes. Perhaps it is better to rewrite your code with new version of ChartJS/ And now it is already v2.5

Comment: @KirillMatrosov Please tell me how to solve this issue??

Answer (score 0):

Switching to a new major version of any software package is more or less [guaranteed to break](http://semver.org/). You will have to manually patch all your code.

Chart.js does not seem to have an upgrade guide so the advice is to do it manually: http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#notes-previous-versions. The process will differ per project of course.